# EC2 User Data Script .sh file and Manual Execute Differ

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am trying to execute the following user data script

```
sudo wget https://files.mysite.com/downloads/myFile.tar -P /opt
sudo tar -xvf /opt/myTar.tar -C /opt
sudo /opt/myFile.sh
```

When I execute the .sh file manually I see this:

```
Extracting...
Unpacking...
Cleaning up...
Complete
```

and it creates a directory in `/opt/myDirectory`

I **do** see the console in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.sh` but it *doesn't* seem to create the directory when run as part of the userdata script.

Comment: Anything relevant in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log?

Answer (score 3):

You're calling a shell script within a shell script, so you need to make sure:

1. have this as the first line of your ec2 user data script  `#!/bin/bash`
2. call `myFile.sh` with the `source` command (alias is `.`) like this: `. /opt/myFile.sh` so it will run the myFile script

Note: the ec2 user data script runs as root so you do not need to have `sudo` each time you run a command.

Comment: Agreed. See a sample User Data script on: [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

Comment: #!/bin/bash
wget https://example.com/myFile.tar -P /opt
tar -xvf /opt/myFile.tar -C /opt
./opt/mySH.sh

Still getting the Extracting... output proving it ran, but doesn't create the directory.

Comment: do you have a space like `. /opt/mySH.sh` if you're not sure, use `sourcing /opt/mySH.sh`

Comment: yes, tried with and without the space. I'm using the Amazon AMI if it matters?

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 147241898 May 30 12:01 mySH.sh`

`/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

`/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 9: .: /opt/MySH.sh: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: The issue is with the script itself can you confirm the same is working when you run it directly from the instance ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: CD into the directory first.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt
wget https://example.com/myTAR.tar
tar -xvf myTAR.tar
/opt/mySH.sh
```